# Magit: Is there a way I can toggle --ignore-all-space option for the default magit-status buffer?

Tags: emacs, magit

In the magit-status buffer I can press `d-wd` on a file to open a magit-diff buffer with the diff of that specific file without whitespace changes. When I go back to magit-status though, the diffs there still show the original whitespace changes. I'm not sure if this is built into magit already but what I'd like is for the original magit-status buffer to ignore whitespace changes as well (being able to toggle this would be amazing)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `magit-status`, enter the *diff mode* by pressing `d` like you've done.  Make your `-w` change.  Then press `C-x` to see that there is an extended magit menu with more available items.  You'll then see that **`C-s` is a means to Save the settings** you've made (e.g., `--ignore-all-space`) for future sessions.

Comment: This is nice though what I was hoping for was the magit status buffer ignoring whitespace as well.
Saving this setting allows me to see the diff in a new buffer when pressing `dd` on a file but the magit status buffer still shows whitespace

Comment: Thinking on it further though, ignoring whitespace on the magit status buffer doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: @irregular see https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/204#issuecomment-255276768 or my answer below :)

Comment: @irregular, why doesn't it seem like a good idea?

Answer (score 6):

I had just this query. I think it makes sense to be able to ignore whitespace in the status buffer because you'll often want to see 'at a glance' just the significant changes you have made. In particular, when rebasing the extra hassle of switching to another window for this kind of sanity check can disturb what is already a fairly delicate workflow.

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/204#issuecomment-255276768), reproduced for convenience:

> You can press `D` (`magit-diff-refresh-popup`), set the flags you want
> (e.g., `-b` for `--ignore-space-change`), and then hit `g`.

You can also do `C-x C-s` as described in the accepted answer or `w` instead of `g` to save the defaults for again.